# Kendo Grid print all data to excel, not just visible data

Tags: c#, excel, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Let´s say I have grid with 80 items and pagesize is 10, when printing from the controller I want to print all the data, not just the visible data on the first page.

I have good "[Export Grid to Excel](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-grid-to-excel)" test project from Telerik, and I´ve got the export feature all covered and working like a charm. Basically just including the NPOI file and start using it.

Is there a way for me to iterate all the product-data from the DataSourceRequest?

My code sample:

```
public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
//Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
IEnumerable products = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;


//TODO: Get all data but not just the data from the visible page as above!!!


//Create new Excel workbook
var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

//Create new Excel sheet
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();

//(Optional) set the width of the columns
sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 50 * 256);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 50 * 256);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 50 * 256);

//Create a header row
var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

//Set the column names in the header row
headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Product ID");
headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Product Name");
headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Unit Price");
headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Quantity Per Unit");

//(Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);

int rowNumber = 1;

//Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
foreach (Product product in products)
{
    //Create a new row
    var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);

    //Set values for the cells
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(product.ProductID);
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(product.ProductName);
    row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(product.UnitPrice.ToString());
    row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(product.QuantityPerUnit.ToString());
}

//Write the workbook to a memory stream
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
workbook.Write(output);

//Return the result to the end user

return File(output.ToArray(),   //The binary data of the XLS file
    "application/vnd.ms-excel", //MIME type of Excel files
    "GridExcelExport.xls");     //Suggested file name in the "Save as" dialog which will be displayed to the end user

}
```

Comment: So you do not want to use the paging, but you do want to use filtering?

Comment: Well, actually yes @Stef.  But I want to be able to print the excel sheet with complete data. However, if the user has reordered columns, sorted columns, or done anything to the grid then I want that to infect itself on to the excel creation in the controller, therefore I kind of need filtering too :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I stumbled upon an answer that works.  @Stef answer got me on the right track although I didn´t actually use his answer, I will therefore up his answer for the help.  I found a way to count the number of pages, and then simply edited the DataSourceRequest for each page.  This way ensures me all the pages from the database.  I hope this helps others in the future  :)

```
public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
//Count pages to use as iterator when adding to list
var pages = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Total/request.PageSize;

//Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
//IEnumerable products = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;

//Get the data representing the current grid state - page, sort and filter
var products = new List<Product>();

//To ensure all pages get fetched from db
for (int i = 1; i < pages + 1; i++)
{
    request.Page = i;
    IEnumerable prod = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
    products.AddRange(prod.Cast<Product>().ToList());
}

//Create new Excel workbook
var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

//Create new Excel sheet
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();

//(Optional) set the width of the columns
sheet.SetColumnWidth(0, 10 * 256);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 50 * 256);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(2, 50 * 256);
sheet.SetColumnWidth(3, 50 * 256);

//Create a header row
var headerRow = sheet.CreateRow(0);

//Set the column names in the header row
headerRow.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Product ID");
headerRow.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Product Name");
headerRow.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("Unit Price");
headerRow.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue("Quantity Per Unit");

//(Optional) freeze the header row so it is not scrolled
sheet.CreateFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);

int rowNumber = 1;

//Populate the sheet with values from the grid data
foreach (Product product in products)
{
    //Create a new row
    var row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNumber++);

    //Set values for the cells
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(product.ProductID);
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue(product.ProductName);
    row.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue(product.UnitPrice.ToString());
    row.CreateCell(3).SetCellValue(product.QuantityPerUnit.ToString());
}

//Write the workbook to a memory stream
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
workbook.Write(output);

//Return the result to the end user

return File(output.ToArray(),   //The binary data of the XLS file
    "application/vnd.ms-excel", //MIME type of Excel files
    "GridExcelExport.xls");     //Suggested file name in the "Save as" dialog which will be displayed to the end user
}
```

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be a bug in this code when the number of rows is less than the page size, you don't get any rows returned. For example, if the page size is 10, and there is only 1 row, `Total / PageSize` gets evaluated as 0, and so the for loop will get skipped.

Comment: @RamiA. Good point. You could of course just check if Total is less than Pagesize before dividing, then you would just set it to 1 or something like that ;)

Answer (score 2):

The source from the DataSourceRequest class can be found [here](https://github.com/kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers/blob/master/Kendo.DynamicLinq/DataSourceRequest.cs).

Probably if you disable the paging properties, you'll get all filtered + sorted data:

```
public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
  request.Take = 9999999;
  request.Skip = 0;

  // Get the data representing the current grid state : sort and filter
  IEnumerable products = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use javascript to print all data to excel, like below

```
function ExportToCSV() {

         var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
         var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
             data: dataSource.data(),
             filter: dataSource.filter()
         });

         filteredDataSource.read();
         var data = filteredDataSource.view();

         var result = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel,";

         result += "<table><tr><th>ProductID</th><th>ProductName</th><th>UnitPrice</th><th>Discontinued</th><th>UnitsInStock</th><th>Category</th></tr>";

         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             result += "<tr>";

             result += "<td>";
             result += data[i].ProductID;
             result += "</td>";

             result += "<td>";
             result += data[i].ProductName;
             result += "</td>";

             ..

             result += "</tr>";
         }

             result += "</table>";
             if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                 window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]), 'export.xls');
             } else {
                 window.open(result);
             }


             e.preventDefault();
         }
```

hope this may help

Comment: Thank you for that @AbbasGaliyakot but your method prints the first page fine, but not data from other pages.